# Need page to wait for php to finish

Tags: php, mysql, http

Simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

My php code takes a really long time to process because I'm generating a report from a large database. I coded an html table to display the results in a web page, but the page loads (and gets sent to clients) before my php code finishes because all the table values are empty. I run the query on phpMyAdmin and it works, but it just takes a long time. Ideas? Are there any other ways I can display the report in a table format besides seeing it in a webpage? Can I make the webpage wait until the code finishes?

Comment: if table values are empty, its very like that the query doesnt work on the live server. maybe you ar emissing a column. I would suggest running the query on a sandbox and throwing a die after to make sure you have an array of values. Also another problem could be capitalization, sometimes itll be fine in phpadmin, but not for server.

Comment: By default, PHP waits until the script is fully interpreted (or default time limit is reached). Is your query running as asyncronous? Show some code.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Can you show us a piece of code? Do you use asynchron code? In general "php is waiting" for the result of your query result. Maybe there is an error in your html syntax, which breaks the code? Did you view the source code of the web page? Are there errors or exceptions in your script?

Comment: It's just a query which probably wouldn't make sense to you guys unless you know the database schema and it runs on php my admin. For the php code, I simply use mysqli_query and  mysqli_fetch_assoc. There were no errors thrown. I'm not sure what running asynchronous means exactly. Is that by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches

one is using

```
ob_start();
// processing
ob_flush();
flush();
```

the next is adding pagination, aka limiting the result size.

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,10`

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10,10`

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20,10`

of course it all depends on your code, without seeing your code there's only guessing what the reason might be

Comment: This is probably the best way and what I was looking for, but my query is way too long (hundreds of thousands of rows) and the browser probably timeout by saying "This website is offline"

Comment: the query itself or the result?
sounds weird that there are no values. usually php waits until there is a result. try doing `var_dump($row);` to see if you didn't have a typo in the array keys or if you need to add aliases.
if limit isn't helping you might try to create indexes for those fields being queried.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make the webpage wait until the code finishes?

It's really, *really* difficult to write PHP code which implements asynchronous database calls - which it would need to do if the PHP script completes before the MySQL script. Just change strip out all the asynchronous handlers in the PHP code and make the MySQL calls blocking and it will not exit before the queries complete - but I very much doubt that is what your code really is doing.

> but the page loads (and gets sent to clients)

This is confused too - if you're generating HTMLthen the page is laoded *after* the HTML is sent to the client - not before.

> Simple question

No it's not - it's very confused!

Answer (score 0):

**The prudent way**

One of the correct approaches, at least one I'd recommend, would be to, upon request from the user, add the job to a queue that is handled by a background process, for example, a PHP command line script running from a cron job. While that is going on, you can periodically request job status from the server via an AJAX call from your webpage, display progress, if you can, and present the user with the result once the job is finished. Since command line PHP scripts don't have time limits, you don't have to worry about timeouts.

Another way is what is implemented, for example, in 37signals' Highrise - they take the request add a job but display a page saying "It will be ready when it's ready," and when it is ready, they send an email to the user saying "Here's your file, come here and download."

**The quick fix**

To answer the question "Can I make the webpage wait until the code finishes?" – there is the [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried it before, but the web page is sent to client before the code completes

Comment: Maybe you just need a longer time limit. Anyway, I added a section with another way you could do it.